# disk usage for each normal user in the system in Linux Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora

How I write a script that show me the disk usage for each normal user in the system in Linux Fedora.

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Include a line like the following in your script.

```
du -s /home/*
```

Note, in a large filesystem it will take a while to run.  Also, if you are not running as root, any directories you don't have permission to access won't be included in the totals.  If you wish to suppress error messages about directories you can't read, add `2>/dev/null` to the end of the command.

Comment: that's was great hhhhhhhh thankssss sir